# Wordpress + multi custom post + one loop

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, title, custom-type

I have a question about worpdress and custom post type. I have created a job board with 2 custom type, one is for the companies who's registered an account and another for company who post mission. So one company can have multiple missions.

My question is, is it possible to have multiple custom post type in one loop ?

More details , each post type have a title like `<?php the_title();?>` and I cannot display each title for each custom post in one loop. I tried everything.

Comment: you can use any number of post types in one loop. You just need to use 'post_type' parameter of the WP_Query as an array. Here is an example, 'post_type' => array('post_type_one', 'post_type_two')

Comment: Yeah i know that but how can i do to show the title of both custom post type in the same loop ?

Comment: the_title() function will display the title regardless of the post type. But if you need like.... different layouts for two post types etc, you can check for the post type using "if" condition inside the loop.

Comment: So i can do this for example : if post-type = "a thing" show the_title() that corresponds?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of post types in the args list for wp_query.

```
$args = array(
/** other arguments here **/
'post_type' => array('post_type_one', 'post_type_two'
)
$results = new WP_Query($args);
if($results->have_posts()) : while($results->have_posts()): $results->the_post();
/** if you need different loops for different post types */
if(get_post_type() == 'post_type_one'){
the_title(true);
/** your rest of content code here - for post type one */
} else {
the_title(true);
/** content for the second post type */
}
endwhile; endif;
```

I think you can manage everything else.